# Primefaces <p:blockUI> hidding growl <p:growl> after releasing

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, blockui

I'm trying to update  message by clicking button from backing bean and in the same time after clicking button I'm trying to block this button to avoid doubleclick. Blocking occurs successfully and message appears, but after the unblocking message disappears. This happens pretty quickly. And I want the message in growl stay longer.
My .jsf snippet.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="messages" />
    <p:blockUI block="button" widgetVar="block"/>
        <p:dataTable var="item" id="table" value="#{bean.lazyModel}"
            lazy="true">
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton value="#{item.actionBtn}" 
                    update=":form:messages" action="#{bean.action}"
                    oncomplete="filterTableFromPanel();PF('block').hide()"
                    onclick="PF('block').show()">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable> 
</h:form>
```

In backing bean all just as usual.

```
public void action(){
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

Please, forgive me for possible mistakes, snipet  is trimmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem using p:remoteCommand.

```html
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="messages" />
    <p:blockUI block="button" widgetVar="block"/>
    <p:remoteCommand name="addMessage"
   action="#{bean.addMessage}"
   update=":form:messages" />
        <p:dataTable var="item" id="table" value="#{bean.lazyModel}"
            lazy="true">
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton value="#{item.actionBtn}" 
                    update=":form:messages" action="#{bean.action}"
                    oncomplete="filterTableFromPanel();PF('block').hide(); addMessage()"
                    onclick="PF('block').show()">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable> 
</h:form>
```

In backing bean I've add somethhing like this:

```html
public void addMessage(){
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, "msg");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the option of setting the `sticky` or `life`:

- `sticky` to keep the `growl` to stay visible until the user closes the growl component manually
- `life` to set a timeout period for the component. This value will determine how long the message is visible for, and then it disappears after the `life` elapses. Set this value in milliseconds `life="1200"` (default is `6000`)

Comment: Thank you, but I've tried to go this way with the same result. Also I've tried to do all like in this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml example (part Basic) where blockUI works  correct with growl, but for me it didn't work.

Comment: Which one have you tried specifically @SergeyVasnev ?

Comment: As I said I've tried to adapt for my case the example from part **Basic** - the first example on the tutorial page where described the case similar to mine, but for me it doesn't work.

Comment: None of the examples on the site use the sticky of life attribute. You're saying you've used both and nothing worked? @SergeyVasnev

Comment: I know what none of the examples on those site uses those attributes. I've added this as an additional info. And as I said I've used this 'life' and 'sticky' attributes. It didn't help.